# Want to validate a string using property in C#

Tags: c#, .net, properties

So, I want to validate my string obj.CategoryName (which is a **property** as u can see) which should **only contain spaces and alphabets** but when it is being passed to set accessor as **obj.CategoryName="1322"**, it is not validating it and still printing it while it should not. Rather it should print the else statement. Below is the code, please check:

```
namespace CategoryBL
{
    public class Category
    {
        private int categoryId;
        private string categoryName;

        public int CategoryId { 
            get
            {
                return categoryId;
            }
            set
            {
                categoryId = value;
            }
            }
        public string CategoryName {
            set
            {
                
                if (Regex.IsMatch(categoryName, "^[a-zA-Z ]+$"))
                {
                    categoryName = value;
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("enter correct format");
            }
            get
            {
                return categoryName;
            } 
            
        }

        public Category(int categoryId,string categoryName)
        {
            this.categoryId = categoryId;
            this.categoryName = categoryName;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace EncapsulationUIL
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            Category obj = new Category(101,"Varun gupta");
            obj.CategoryId = 102;
            obj.CategoryName = "1322";
            
            
            Console.WriteLine("{0} \n{1}", obj.CategoryId, obj.CategoryName);
        }
    }
}
```

HELP IS MUCH APPRECIATED. THANKS

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: `if (Regex.IsMatch(value, "^[a-zA-Z ]+$"))`: note `value` instead of `categoryName`

Answer (score 1):

When validating within `set` accessor you should chech `value`, not *backing field* `categoryName` which should have already been valid:

```
public string CategoryName {
  get => categoryName;
  set {
    // We should check value, not categoryName 
    if (Regex.IsMatch(value, "^[a-zA-Z ]+$"))
      categoryName = value;
    else
      // I'd rather throw exception here 
      Console.WriteLine("enter correct format");
  }
}
```

You may want to add validation into constructor as well:

```
public Category(int categoryId, string categoryName) {
  if (categoryName == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(categoryName));

  if (!Regex.IsMatch(categoryName, "^[a-zA-Z ]+$"))
    throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid {nameof(categoryName)} format", 
                                  nameof(categoryName));

  this.categoryId = categoryId;
  this.categoryName = categoryName;
}
```